# How to store user customizable queries?

Tags: django, python-3.5

I would like to allow a bunch of my users to run arbitrary and periodical queries.

So far, I've managed to create this model:

```
class BasicQuery(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    target_entity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    target_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    compare_value = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    run_every = models.ForeignKey(QueryFrequency)
```

and the function which executes it :

```
def rule_runner(rule):
    target_entity = rule.target_entity
    fieldname = rule.target_field
    val = rule.compare_value

    if rule.operator:
        cmd = '{}.objects.filter({}__{}={})'.format(rule.target_entity, 
                                                    rule.target_field,
                                                    rule.operator,
                                                    rule.compare_value)
    else:
        cmd = '{}.objects.filter({}={})'.format(rule.target_entity, 
                                                rule.target_field,
                                                rule.compare_value)
    return eval(cmd)
```

But because of the `eval(cmd)`, the code is way too dangerous to go to production, no matter how many tests I'll do before calling this function I'll never feel safe about it. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this purpose in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

You could unpack a dict containing the values, so they can be used dynamically with the filter method. And about the `rule.target_entity`, you can use `importlib.import_module(str)` and `getattr(module, str)` to get it:

```
import importlib


def rule_runer(rule):
    model = getattr(importlib.import_module('app.models'), 'Model')

    if rule.operator:        
        field = rule.target_field
    else:
        field = '{}__{}'.format(rule.target_field, rule.operator)

    return model.objects.filter(**{field: rule.compare_value})
```

To unpack a dict is to put `**` before it. This can be used to dynamically set the function's arguments, so the **dict keys** will be the arguments names and the **dict values** will be these arguments values.

`importlib.import_module` will allow you to import any module within your `PYTHONPATH`, which usually includes all your django apps paths (so `app.models` shouldn't be a problem), by using a string.

This is definitely safer than using `eval` and you do have to check if the module's path or the model exists to avoid throwing a `ModuleNotFoundError` (`ImportError` if < Python 3.6) or `AttributeError`.